# PHP how to write echo inside a copy function

Tags: php, html

Pretty straight forward. I want to do something like this:

```
copy("/home/website/website.org/users/test.php", "/home/website/website.org/users/user/echo $_SESSION['name'];.html");
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't echo something when you're in the middle of the statement. Concatenate it instead:

```
 copy("/home/website/website.org/users/test.php", "/home/website/website.org/users/user/".$_SESSION['name'].".html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate It

```
copy("/home/website/website.org/users/test.php", "/home/website/website.org/users/user/".$_SESSION['name'].".html");
```